# Can two same single RAM chips start to work in dual channel?

Tags: memory, ddr2, dual-channel, ddr

Do i *need* to buy a dual-channel memory kit in order to use Dual Channel?

If I have a single 2GB chip and a mainboard which supports Dual Channel, can I expect to have dual channel enabled if I buy exactly the same chip and put the two of them together?

Specifically, my current memory is Kingston HyperX DDR2 2GB 800MHz CL5 (KHX6400D2/2G).

*(Yes, I know that changing my motherboard and getting DDR3 would be even better, but it would be overkill for my needs right now.)*

Comment: For reference: I have contacted Kingston and they told me that it's possible that two chips (even if they are the same model), when bought separately, may or may not form a "like pair" (? no details provided here) and I have no guarantee that they will work in dual channel - unless bought in a single kit. For me it worked- after installing a second chip of the same model, I had dual channel working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will be fine if it is identical and they are placed in the proper slots (IE: blue and blue or black and black etc). I don't know how different they can be before they cause issues I usually just try and match speed and timing (I don't worry about manufacturer) and have never had a problem..

Comment: As long as speeds, timing, and voltage are the same you should be fine.  Obviously two identical chips should be just fine.  (You can have a little bit of variance for non-identical chips but this will vary from situation to situation.)

Comment: So there is really no something such as "dual channel enabled RAM chip" and "dual channel disabled RAM chip"? I've heard that someone had a problem with setup of two identical Patriot ddr2 ram chips...